# ARC releasing subclassed NSObjects, but not custom NSObjects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

In a small RTS project, i have a list of buttons, each with a building object allocated to them. Some buildings are very generic, but others are quite special, and i have therefor made some of the buildings as subclasses.

When I make a list of buttons, where they each have a PEHouse object, everything works fine.

But once one of those PEHouses is a subclassed PEHouse, it gets released immediately, and I can't understand why.

The buttons have this property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) PEHouse *linkedHouse;
```

The house have these values :

```
@interface PEHouse : NSObject {
    NSString *title;
}
@property (nonatomic) BOOL is_locked;
```

And my Tower has this setup :

```
#import "PEHouse.h"

@interface PETower : PEHouse <NSObject>

-(void)secondAction;
+ (PETower*)createTower;

@end
```

When I spawn a list of regular objects like this :

```
DLog(@"Building menu");
    if ([key isEqualToString:@"button_income"]) {
        [GMBuildMenu buttonFromBuilding:[PEHouse newSawmill] withIndex:1 inDict:dict];
        [GMBuildMenu buttonFromBuilding:[PEHouse newQuarry] withIndex:2 inDict:dict];
        [GMBuildMenu buttonFromBuilding:[PEHouse newIronMine] withIndex:3 inDict:dict];
        [GMBuildMenu buttonFromBuilding:[PEHouse newMiscShop] withIndex:4 inDict:dict];
        [GMBuildMenu buttonFromBuilding:[PEHouse newWeaponsShop] withIndex:5 inDict:dict];
        [GMBuildMenu buttonFromBuilding:[PEHouse newArmorShop] withIndex:6 inDict:dict];
        [GMBuildMenu buttonFromBuilding:[PEHouse newBazaar] withIndex:7 inDict:dict];
        [GMBuildMenu buttonFromBuilding:[PEHouse newTreasury] withIndex:8 inDict:dict];
        return YES;
    }
```

Everything works well. When i spawn just one of my subsetted building buttons like this :

```
 if ([key isEqualToString:@"button_military"]) {
        [GMBuildMenu buttonFromBuilding:[PEHouse newTower] withIndex:1 inDict:dict];
}
```

The object is released immediately after...

Does anyone have a clue why this differentiation takes place ?

**Update**

The code looks like this :

```
+(OpenGLButton*)buttonFromBuilding:(PEHouse*)house withIndex:(int)index inDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)dict {
    OpenGLButton *new = [GMButtonMenu addButtonToMenu:dict withLabel:house.button_art andShowname:house.title];
    new.linkedHouse = house;
    CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(20, ((30)*index), (28*[GMButtonMenu globalGUIScale]), (28*[GMButtonMenu globalGUIScale]));
    new.location = buttonFrame;
    new.index = index;
    new.details = house.desc;
    return new;
}
```

In PEHouse we find :

```
+ (PETower *)newTower {
    PETower *new = [PETower createTower];
    return new;
}


+ (PEHouse *)newSawmill {
    PEHouse *new = [PEHouse createDefault];
    new.title = @"Sawmill";

    new.is_large = YES;
    return new;
}
```

Comment: What does `buttonFromBuilding:withIndex:inDict:` look like? According to normal Cocoa conventions it should merely return a button with a non-owning reference but I get the sense you're using it to do something else?

Comment: Can you paste these 2 methods: `sawMill` and `newTower`?

Comment: besides the very poor naming choice (`new` is a method of NSObject), can you provide also the code of `addButtonToMenu:WithLabel:andShowname:`?

Comment: BTW:  `is_locked` should just be `isLocked`.

Answer (score 1):

First, what is the signature of the [GMBuildMenu buttonFromBuilding:...] class method ?
According to your code, it looks like it is :

```
+(void)buttonFromBuilding:(PEHouse *)house withIndex:(int)index inDict:(NSDictionary *)dict
```

However, by convention, method named as such are supposed to return a button:

```
+(UIButton *)buttonFromBuilding:(PEHouse *)house withIndex:(int)index inDict:(NSDictionary *)dict
```

It would be interesting to know what your method does with the PEHouse object. Does it strongly own it ?

Comment: Added the requested function to the OP

Comment: OK, so `GMBuildMenu buttonFromBuilding` returns a button but your "Building menu" code doesn't look like it's doing anything with it. If nothing owns the button in the end, it can get released as soon as the  ending brace is reached.

Comment: The dict still owns the button, and everything works well when regular houses are being used. The houses are only deallocated, if they are custom PEHouse versions.

Comment: Did you try to declare the interface with just `@interface PETower : PEHouse` instead of `@interface PETower : PEHouse <NSObject>` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think here it's a matter of the convention ARC is following.

What ARC does is to release everything coming from `new`, `alloc`, `retain`, `copy` or `mutableCopy` and considering the factory methods as autoreleased.

I suspect that having a class method returning an `OpenGLButton` instance will make ARC to insert an autorelease call at the end of your method, doing something like

```
+(OpenGLButton*)buttonFromBuilding:(PEHouse*)house withIndex:(int)index inDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)dict {
    OpenGLButton *new = [GMButtonMenu addButtonToMenu:dict withLabel:house.button_art andShowname:house.title];
    // ...
    return [new autorelease];
}
```

Then since you're not assigning the return value to anything, it gets released as soon it goes out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

`+[GMBuildMenu buttonFromBuilding:withIndex:inDict:]` returns the newly-created button, but you don't store that reference anywhere.  Since you say most of your buttons don't get deallocated immediately, I deduce that the method must store a reference to the newly-created button somewhere.

Looking at the method, I see this line:

```
OpenGLButton *new = [GMButtonMenu addButtonToMenu:dict withLabel:house.button_art andShowname:house.title];
```

None of the other lines in `buttonFromBuilding:withIndex:inDict:` store `new` anywhere, so I deduce that `+[GMButtonMenu addButtonToMenu:withLabel:andShowname:]` stores a reference to the new button somewhere.

I guess it stores the button in the first argument.  You are passing `dict` as that argument.

Investigate these possible reasons for your tower button to be deallocated unexpectedly:

1. `dict` is nil when you call `[GMBuildMenu buttonFromBuilding:[PEHouse newTower] withIndex:1 inDict:dict]`.
2. `dict` is not nil but is itself deallocated shortly after `[GMBuildMenu buttonFromBuilding:[PEHouse newTower] withIndex:1 inDict:dict]` returns.